# C++ function prototypes?

Tags: c++

Here goes newbie question number 5, but I don't have a teacher.. so.. anyhow here we go:

I'm wondering if is necessary to have function prototypes at the top of the file, instead of putting the `main` function to the end of the file and create all the function at the top of the file. As far as I can tell, VC++ and G++ both are not complaining. Is there standards that disallows me to do so?

It seems rather annoying to have to change the prototype when you change a function parameters and return types.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void say_hi(){
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    say_hi();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declares but does not define the function `say_hi`:

```
void say_hi();
```

This both declares and defines the function `say_hi`:

```
void say_hi(){
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
}
```

You can declare a function many times; you can only define it once.

A function must be declared in the file *before* you can call it.  A function must be defined *somewhere*--in the same file before or after you call it or maybe even in a different file.

So, yes, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Although not specifically asked for, the final bit of information is why example code ends up written this way. One reason is that it ensures no circular dependencies; if A call B and B calls A, they both can't be defined first. The other is that it more naturally leads to the separation of the function definitions into a separate file, at which point you need the forward declarations before `main`.

Comment: Then why do we need function prototype at all?

Comment: @ultimate, for recursive calls. Indirect recursion, containers that can hold themselves etc. They all require prototypes so they can refer to themselves or derivations of themselves later on.

Comment: @ultimate: because without it, how will the compiler know what the function is, or even that it is a function? Some languages can get away with guessing, but C++ is not one of them.

Comment: Also, there's the "one definition rule." If you include two definitions for the same function, your program wil fail to link. SO if two files both want access to the same function, one needs a prototype.

Comment: So it's best to put the prototype there? I'm in the habit of doing so, though as of right now it still seems annoying. (side question: Can IDEs help eliminate this annoyance somehow?)

Comment: If you need to use a function in multiple source files, you should declare the function in a header file and define it in a single source file (due to the "one definition rule" Dennis mentions, you can only define it once but you can declare it as many times as you want).  If you are only using a function in a single source file, I would argue that you should, wherever possible, declare and define it at the top of the file in an unnamed namespace (`namespace { void foo() { } }`).

Comment: I admit though that I'm not the best person to ask about best practices here:  I have a tendency to make everything a template, so most (98%+) of my code ends up in header files.

Comment: Defined 'in the file' is somewhat misleading. Defined 'in the translation unit' is more accurate. Of course, the term 'translation unit' is not particularly self-explanatory.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: "why do we need"... as well as the relatively rare utility in recursive code, prototypes/declarations are really important for describing functions in already-compiled objects and libraries (the source code for which might not even be in C++).  Some (weird ;-P) people just like structuring their files "top-down" too - higher level logic/functions followed by increasingly low-level detail - feeling it is more self-documenting: that requires the low-level functions be declared earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; if you define all your functions above where they are called, you don't need function prototypes. The actual function *definition* serves the same purpose as a separate *declaration*.

Answer (score 1):

This works when you have tiny functions. It works less well when they get long. Or when you have more than one file of code. As a matter of style, many teachers demand that even tiny applications be written with the structure that serves large applications well.

Comment: When say_hi() is 400 lines long, and there are a number of other long functions in there, finding main() is a challenge. Therefore eventually most C++ developers have multiple files, header files, and so on. Since that's where people end up, there are those who teach you to start that way, even when you can't see a reason for doing so. The question asked "is this ok?" and it is, but some might say to do it differently. I think I know why they say that.

Comment: @Kate: well, in the case of `main`, finding it isn't much of a challenge -- it's going to be the last function in the file ;-p

Comment: @Steve - and when main() is 2000 lines long, where's the start of it?

Comment: What does the function length have to do with splitting files? I still don't get what teachers have to do with this either... You have a really rambling way of thinking.

Comment: If someone insists on writing 2000 line functions, then *something* in there is going to be difficult to find. I don't think the problem starts with *how many* terrible, terrible functions there are, or how many files they appear in, the problem is that there are any. But since you ask, in my text editor "go to matching bracket" is CTRL+B. Writers of very long functions are advised to (a) find out what it is in their text editor, and (b) stop it :-)

Comment: @Steve, Or even better, "go to function definition". What possible use can a function header be in tracking down the function body anyway? I personally think the whole function header thing should be gone and C++ compilers do two parses over the file and generate the header list themselves, like C#/Java compilers do already.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that you rarely see such monolithic single file programs except when learning the language, so you are more likely to see superfluous prototypes from a teacher. Not a well worded answer, but reasonable.

Comment: @Blindy: to be fair, a good file structure does help find function definitions, if it's followed consistently. `main` is at the top of `main.cpp`, `say_hi` is at the top of `say_hi.cpp`, etc. Equally it helps find the function definition if `say_hi` is defined in `say_hi.h` - but somewhere down the road your project will get big enough that you want to move some functions in to `.cpp` files. I can easily believe that teachers tend to demand this be done early on.

Comment: @Steve that still has nothing to do with function prototypes though. Plus it gets murkier when you throw classes into the mix :)

Comment: @Blindy: it has to do with prototypes in the sense that *if* you're putting each function in its own translation unit, *then* you're going to use prototypes. Hence, "Or when you have more than one file of code". But the questioner seems set to define all the functions in the same file regardless of which order they're defined, at least for this program, so I agree the answer contains some speculation that may not be relevant. It's not the first such on SO...